# How do you minimize software tools installation and configuration on newly installed OS (Linux/Mac OS X)?

Tags: installation, automation

Once a year, I re-install my OS. After every install, I have to install a lot of tools (Xcode, Tmux, Iterm2, etc ..). This is time consuming (about 8 hours to re-install everything and restore config files) and error prone.

**Goal:**

I already reduced the number of software I use on a daily basis but I would like to go even further by automating the install and configuration setup.

**Solutions**

Here are solutions I have in mind (from best to worst):

1. Use a bash script to install tools/restore config files. (Eg: Executing vim for the first time retrieves vim plugins and install plugins dependencies.)
2. Use a Virtual Machine as "Template VM" with tools/conf files pre installed and configured. (I am already doing this on Ubuntu as I develop in virtual machine) but every time I need to add a new tools, I will have to setup it up twice (in the "Template VM" and the VM I am currently using).

Are there better ways to achieve this goal ?

Requirements:
Ideally I would like the solution to be both applicable on Mac OS X and GNU/Linux (Ubuntu).

Comment: Maybe Chef is a possible solution and cross platform ? http://www.mug.im/blog/2012/10/01/how-to-setup-your-mac-automatically-with-chef/

Comment: Upgrading, instead of fresh install?